# How to end a function before it's called again

Tags: javascript, loops, dom-events

I have an `addEventListener` in my `loadGame()` and every time I hit the <kbd>newGame</kbd> button it launches `loadGame()`, but I have no return value in `loadGame()` so every time I hit the <kbd>newGame</kbd> button it relaunches the game, but the `eventListeners` of `template[i]` seem to overlap, so if I hit <kbd>newGame</kbd> 10 times, then hit the else statement of the loop, it'll run `tryAgain()` 10 times. How do I exit the function I'm on when hitting <kbd>newGame</kbd>? I tried adding a return statement at the end of `loadGame()` but that did nothing.

```
newGame.addEventListener('click', function(){
    changeDifficulty();
});

 function changeDifficulty(){       
            loadGame();         
    }
```

Loop in `loadGame()`:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
    //add colors to squares
    template[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

    template[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;

        if(clickedColor === correctColor) {
            clearInterval(timeout);
            message.innerHTML = "Correct!"; 
            newGame.textContent = "Play Again?";
        }
        else {
            fails++;
            tryAgain(difficulty);
            this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
            message.innerHTML = "Wrong!"
        }
   });
```

Comment: im not trying to break out of the loop

Comment: if you return false in any line of your function it will end it.

Comment: Check  clearInterval(timeout);

Comment: where would i put the return? I added at end of function and at win condition and neither work. clearInterval is for something else that is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove the event listeners before registering new ones:

```
function loadGame() {
    // <...>
    for (var i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
        //add colors to squares
        template[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

        template[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    }
    // <...>
}

function changeDifficulty() {
    // remove all event listeners
    for (var i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {
        template[i].removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
    }     
    // Then call loadgame
    loadGame();         
}

function clickHandler(e) { // We need to be able to reference this function by name
    var clickedColor = e.target.style.backgroundColor;

    if(clickedColor === correctColor) {
        clearInterval(timeout);
        changeColorsOnWin(correctColor, template);
        message.innerHTML = "Correct!"; 
        newGame.textContent = "Play Again?";
    }
    else {
        fails++;
        tryAgain(difficulty);
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#232323";
        message.innerHTML = "Wrong!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it your way and I seem to be having an issue with the line "var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;" i made clickedColor global but still getting error. The error is "this" is undefined. It outputs the first template[i] but not the rest

Comment: @Trippze: I've updated my answer a little. Should work now, assuming `this` was supposed to be the clicked element.

Comment: what do i pass in clickhandler for "template[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);" I did "template[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler(template[i]);" but that still says its undefined

Comment: @Trippze: Did you look at my edited code? You don't call the function in `addEventListener`. You only reference it.

Comment: how do I add a second parameter to clickhandler, if I can only reference it? because i need a difficulty parameter for the tryAgain() function in clickHandler. like clickHandler(difficulty, e)

Comment: @Trippze: That's not weird. The `click` event ___only___ passes an event object to the handler. There's only that one, single parameter. If you add a parameter in the function, in front of `e`, that one will contain the click event, and the `e` will be undefined.

Comment: @Trippze: __[Here's an example](https://jsbin.com/gubezehudo/edit?js,output)__. Open the console and click the button.